# Want to use SignalR in Windows Application to sync my clients

Tags: winforms, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

i want to create a application where i will use a Windows application as a server and a web application as a client. 
Now i want to sync my client(web application) with my server(Windows application).
Both Web and Windows applications are in .NET4.0
Can any one help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

SignalR supports self-hosting. See https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/SignalR.Hosting.Self

You should be able to start the host directly from inside a Windows application or a Windows service. Your question wasn't clear, but I inferred an application due to the winforms tag on the question.

As long as your application is running, web clients should be able to communicate with your SignalR server code.

Comment: I'm unable to use a windows application as a client to a SignalR server hosted on a Windows Application.